KeyboardListener in ListView.builder does not bring the current value
I have a list of data that I am searching on. I want to catch the event of pressing the down arrow on the keyboard so I used widget:KeyboardListener.
There is indeed a listener for the event, but each time it prints the last entry in the list and not the entry I clicked on with the down arrow.
Here is the code:
 itemBuilder: (context, index) => Builder(builder: (context) {
                final myCurrentItem=snapshot.data![index]!.searchKey;
                if (selected == index) {
                  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                    Scrollable.ensureVisible(context,
                        alignment: 0.1, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
                  });
                }
                return TextFieldTapRegion(
                    onTapOutside: (x) {
                      if (widget.onTapOutside != null) widget.onTapOutside!(x);
                      _searchFocus!.unfocus();
                    },

             
                    child: Material(
                  
                        color: widget.suggestionsDecoration == null
                            ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface
                            : Colors.transparent,

              
                        child: InkWell(
                         key: snapshot.data![index]!.key,
                          hoverColor:
                              widget.suggestionsDecoration?.hoverColor ??
                                  Theme.of(context).hoverColor,
                          onTap: () =>
                              onSuggestionTapped(snapshot.data![index]!),
                      
                          child: KeyboardListener(
                         
                           focusNode: widget.focusNode!,
                        
                            autofocus: true,
                            
                            onKeyEvent: (value) {
                              if (value.logicalKey ==
                                  LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
                          
                                print(
                                    "${snapshot.data![index]!.searchKey}  snapshot.data![index]!.searchKey");
                              }
                            },
                          
                            child: Container(
                                
                              key: snapshot.data![index]!.key,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              decoration: widget.suggestionItemDecoration
                                      ?.copyWith(
                                    color: selected == index
                                        ? widget.suggestionsDecoration
                                                ?.selectionColor ??
                                            Theme.of(context).highlightColor
                                        : null,
                                    border: widget
                                            .suggestionItemDecoration?.border ??
                                        Border(
                                          bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: widget.marginColor ??
                                                onSurfaceColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                  ) ??
                                  BoxDecoration(
                                    color: selected == index
                                        ? widget.suggestionsDecoration
                                                ?.selectionColor ??
                                            Theme.of(context).highlightColor
                                        : null,
                                    border: index == snapshot.data!.length - 1
                                        ? null
                                        : Border(
                                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                              color: widget.marginColor ??
                                                  onSurfaceColor
                                                      .withOpacity(0.1),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                  ),
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: snapshot.data![index]!.child ??
                                        Text(
                                          snapshot.data![index]!.searchKey,
                                          style: widget.suggestionStyle,
                                        ),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )));
              }),
            ),
          );

